# UI Automation Control Desktop Application and Click on Menu Strip

Tags: c#, winforms, menu, ui-automation, desktop-application

I am using UI Automation to click on a Menu Strip control.
I have already pre filled the textboxes and can now invoke the button as well.

But I would like to traverse to the Menu Bar select an option lets say File which should open its sub menu items and then click on a sub menu button, let's say Exit.

How can I achieve it, below is my code till now,

```cs
AutomationElement rootElement = AutomationElement.RootElement;

if (rootElement != null)
{
    System.Windows.Automation.Condition condition = new PropertyCondition
        (AutomationElement.NameProperty, "This Is My Title");
    rootElement.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, condition1);
    AutomationElement appElement = rootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, condition);
    
    if (appElement != null)
    {
        foreach (var el in eles)
        {
            AutomationElement txtElementA = GetTextElement(appElement, el.textboxid);
            if (txtElementA != null)
            {
                ValuePattern valuePatternA =
                    txtElementA.GetCurrentPattern(ValuePattern.Pattern) as ValuePattern;
                valuePatternA.SetValue(el.value);
                el.found = true;
            }
        }

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        System.Windows.Automation.Condition condition1 = new PropertyCondition
            (AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, "button1");
        AutomationElement btnElement = appElement.FindFirst
            (TreeScope.Descendants, condition1);

        InvokePattern btnPattern =
            btnElement.GetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern) as InvokePattern;
        btnPattern.Invoke();
```

Answer (score 2):

Menu Items support the [ExpandCollapsePattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.expandcollapsepattern). You can invoke a sub `MenuItem` after you have expanded it. This creates the `MenuItem` descendant objects. If you don't expand the Menu, it has no descendants so there's nothing to invoke.
The invocation is performd using an [InvokePattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.invokepattern)

To get the **`ExpandCollapsePattern`** and the **`InvokePattern`** , use the [TryGetCurrentPattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.automationelement.trygetcurrentpattern) method:

```
[MenuItem].TryGetCurrentPattern(ExpandCollapsePattern.Pattern, out object pattern)

[MenuItem].TryGetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern, out object pattern)
```

If the method returns a successful result, you can then call the [Expand()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.expandcollapsepattern.expand) and [Invoke()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.invokepattern.invoke) methods.

To note that a [MenuBar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.controltype.menubar) Element has `Children`, while a [MenuItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.controltype.menuitem) has `Descendants`. If you use the [FindAll()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.automationelement.findall) method to search for children, you won't find any.

> The [Inspect utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winauto/inspect-objects) is quite useful when coding an UI Automation
>   procedure. It's usually located in:
>
> ```
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64\inspect.exe
> ```
>
> A 32bit version is available (`\bin\x86\` folder).

How to proceed:

- Find the handle of main Window of the Application you want to interact with:

  - [Process.GetProcessesByName()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.getprocessesbyname) (or by ID), [EnumWindows()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumwindows), [FindWindowEx()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-findwindowexw) can be used to get the Window Handle.
- Get the **`MenuBar`** AutomationElement.

  - Note that the `SystemMenu` is also contained in a `MenuBar`, it can be determined using the Element Name, it contains: `"System"` instead of `"Application"`.
- Enumerate the child elements of the `MenuBar` or [FindFirst()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.automationelement.findfirst) one by Name.

  - Note, that the Menu items names and accelerators are localized.
- Expand the Menu, using the **`ExpandCollapsePattern.Expand()`** method, to create its Descendants elements.
- Find one of the Sub-Menu elements by **`Name`** or **`AutomationId`** or **`AccessKey`**.
- Invoke the sub-menu action using the **`InvokePattern.Invoke()`** method.

Of course, the same actions can be repeated to expand and invoke the MenuItems of nested Sub-Menus.

Sample code and helper methods to find and expand the File Menu of `Notepad.exe` and invoke the **`Exit`** MenuItem action:

```
public void CloseNotepad()
{
    IntPtr hWnd = IntPtr.Zero;
    using (Process p = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad").FirstOrDefault()) {
        hWnd = p.MainWindowHandle;
    }
    if (hWnd == IntPtr.Zero) return;
    var window = GetMainWindowElement(hWnd);
    var menuBar = GetWindowMenuBarElement(window);
    var fileMenu = GetMenuBarMenuByName(menuBar, "File");

    if (fileMenu is null) return;

    // var fileSubMenus = GetMenuSubMenuList(fileMenu);
    bool result = InvokeSubMenuItemByName(fileMenu, "Exit", true);
}

private AutomationElement GetMainWindowElement(IntPtr hWnd) 
    => AutomationElement.FromHandle(hWnd) as AutomationElement;

private AutomationElement GetWindowMenuBarElement(AutomationElement window)
{
    var condMenuBar = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.MenuBar);
    var menuBar = window.FindAll(TreeScope.Descendants, condMenuBar)
        .OfType<AutomationElement>().FirstOrDefault(ui => !ui.Current.Name.Contains("System"));
    return menuBar;
}

private AutomationElement GetMenuBarMenuByName(AutomationElement menuBar, string menuName)
{
    var condition = new AndCondition(
        new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.MenuItem),
        new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, menuName)
    );
    if (menuBar.Current.ControlType != ControlType.MenuBar) return null;
    var menuItem = menuBar.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, condition);
    return menuItem;
}

private List<AutomationElement> GetMenuSubMenuList(AutomationElement menu)
{
    if (menu.Current.ControlType != ControlType.MenuItem) return null;
    ExpandMenu(menu);
    var submenus = new List<AutomationElement>();
    submenus.AddRange(menu.FindAll(TreeScope.Descendants,
        new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.MenuItem))
                                               .OfType<AutomationElement>().ToArray());
    return submenus;
}

private bool InvokeSubMenuItemByName(AutomationElement menuItem, string menuName, bool exactMatch)
{
    var subMenus = GetMenuSubMenuList(menuItem);
    AutomationElement namedMenu = null;
    if (exactMatch) {
        namedMenu = subMenus.FirstOrDefault(elm => elm.Current.Name.Equals(menuName));
    }
    else {
        namedMenu = subMenus.FirstOrDefault(elm => elm.Current.Name.Contains(menuName));
    }
    if (namedMenu is null) return false;
    InvokeMenu(namedMenu);
    return true;
}

private void ExpandMenu(AutomationElement menu)
{
    if (menu.TryGetCurrentPattern(ExpandCollapsePattern.Pattern, out object pattern))
    {
        (pattern as ExpandCollapsePattern).Expand();
    }
}

private void InvokeMenu(AutomationElement menu)
{
    if (menu.TryGetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern, out object pattern))
    {
        (pattern as InvokePattern).Invoke();
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear Jimi, Thanks alot for your reply.. I am able to expand the menu bar now but the only issue is it collapses when it reaches to next line of code. So, lets say if i have file --> Open then it will expand file but when i want to click open it will collapse it and therefore it does not find Open and throws a null value exception. How can i hold it or make it expand till the time open is clicked?

Comment: So, you didn't either read what I wrote or you actually used this code. The Open MenuItem Name is `Open... Ctrl+O` (in English), the AccessKey is `o` and AutomationId is `2`. Using the code you see here, you can activate it using the sequence shown in the `CloseNotepad()` method, changing the last command in `bool result = InvokeSubMenuItemByName(fileMenu, "Open", false);`.