# Keep getting System.Windows.Automation.ElementNotAvailableException

Tags: c#, windows, accessibility, ui-automation

I'm trying to make logging of cursor hovered menu items in notepad using Automation framework. But when i i hover the cursor on item i get an exception:

[image]

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException += (sender, eventArgs) =>
{
        Debug.WriteLine(eventArgs.Exception.ToString());
};

Automation.AddAutomationEventHandler(WindowPattern.WindowOpenedEvent,
        AutomationElement.FromHandle(Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad").First().MainWindowHandle), 
        TreeScope.Element, OnNotepadControlAction);
}
```

I also tried to listen for other events (like AutomationElement events, ItemSelectedPattern, InvokePattern, etc.), result is the same.
The only event that i can get without any exceptions is focus change event.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: There's nothing here related to Menus or cursor hovering any UI element. This code is just trying to raise and handle an Automation event when a Window belonging to a Process named `notepad` is opened (i.e. the Notepad's Main Window when a Process of this class is started). The `TreeScope` is set to the element itself `TreeScope.Element`, so only related to the main Window. -- Take the helper classes from here: [UI Automation Control Desktop Application and Click on Menu Strip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56281535/7444103) and add event handlers to Menu Elements as needed.

Comment: AppDomain.FirstChanceException is very misleading.  System.Windows.Automation uses exceptions for flow control.  That's criminal in .NET code, except when you have to.  Like it does, automation is COM-interop based.  Lots of try/catch/return false code in that assembly.  Test an app first before trying to write code, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/inspect-objects