# How to set AutomationId for dynamically created controls in Windows Forms?

Tags: winforms, ui-automation

I'm trying to set AutomationId for dynamically created items. The example code is as following:

```cs
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var menu = new MenuStrip();
    
    var item = new ToolStripMenuItem();
    item.Text = "Plik";
    item.Name = "File";            
    

    var subitem = new ToolStripMenuItem();
    subitem.Text = "Nowy";
    subitem.Name = "New";

    item.DropDownItems.Add(subitem);

    this.Controls.Add(menu);
    menu.Items.Add(item);

    this.MainMenuStrip = menu;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var formHandle = AutomationElement.FromHandle(this.Handle);

    Condition propCondition = new PropertyCondition(
        AutomationElement.NameProperty, "File");

    var menuHandle = formHandle.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, propCondition);
    // menuHandle is null here
    menuHandle.SetFocus();
}
```

Form itself has AutomationId equal to "Form1". However, created menu items doesn't seem to have AutomationID.

How can I manually set AutomationId for dynamically created control?

Comment: `AutomationElement.NameProperty` refers to the Text of a Control.

Comment: I mean, in your context. Since you don't assign the `AccessibleName` of your UI elements. The `Name` of a Control becomes its `AutomationId`, when this Automation property is supported by the element.

Comment: @Jimi, does it happen for dynamically created controls? In the code I tried "AutomationId" earlier, but it didn't work, this is actually my second attempt. Is there a way to specify `AutomationId` manually? Do you know maybe, what is the mechanism under setting AutomationId? Where does OS store it? Is there any access to it?

Comment: When you set the `Name` of a Control that supports the `AutomationId` Property, this is done automatically. You can assign the UIA `Name` property setting the `AccessibleName` property (otherwise the `Text` is used) -- Not all Components make use of or set the `AutomationId` value. MenuItems are among these. You access the Parent MenuStrip (which supports it) and use a `Condition` (`AndCondition`, `OrCondition`, with `ControlType.MenuItem`) to locate child MenuItems.

Comment: An example here: [UI Automation Control Desktop Application and Click on Menu Strip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56281535/7444103)